# Problem switching / navigating from LoginScreen to HomeScreen using Firebase Authentication in React Native App

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build a React Native App. As database, I'm using Firebase and for User Management, I'm using Firebase Authentication (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth?hl=en).
I have a (seemingly) very simple problem. I can create new Users in the app with the firebase function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and login too using the firebase function `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, but after the login, the user is not directed or navigated to the HomeScreen. 
So currently my app only consists of two screens, the login and the home screen. The code for both screens and the App.js as well as the package.json file is provided below.
Some time ago, the firebase authentication did work and I manually navigated users using reactnavigation (https://reactnavigation.org/) between home- and login-screen. But since I had to upgrade firebase to version 10, it seems to not work that way anymore.
While building this basic app, I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONAVmsGW6-M&t=1164s . There, the developer is using TypeScript, but it should work the same way for me according to my opinion.
I think the problematic line of code might be

```
{user ? <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false}} /> : <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false}} />}
```

since there the screen to be displayed is determined in dependance of my user state. I checked that after the call so setUser(user);, the user object is correctly set in the state. I don't understand why the code used in the youtube tutorial does not seem to work for me and why I couldn't get this basic firebase authentication to work. I am very thankful for any tips and ideas and will happily provide more information if needed. Spent some time on this, so thanks in advance for any help!

App.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Login from './screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from './config';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, (user) => {
      console.log('user: ', user);
      setUser(user);
    })
  })

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Login'>
        {user ? <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false}} /> : <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false}} />}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

LoginScreen.js

```
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from '../config';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const auth = FIREBASE_AUTH;

    const signIn = async() => {
        try {
            const response = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
            console.log(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Sign in failed: ' + error.message);
        } 
    }

    const signUp = async() => {
        try {
            const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
            console.log(response);
            alert('Check your emails!');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Registration failed: ' + error.message);
        } 
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput value={email} style={styles.input} placeholder='Email' autoCapitalize='none' onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}></TextInput>
            <TextInput secureTextEntry={true} value={password} style={styles.input} placeholder='Password' autoCapitalize='none' onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}></TextInput>

            <Button title='Login' onPress={signIn} />
            <Button title="Create account" onPress={signUp} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default Login;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginHorizontal: 20, 
        flex: 1, 
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }, 
    input: {
        marginVertical: 4,
        height: 50, 
        borderWidth: 1, 
        borderRadius: 4, 
        padding: 10, 
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    }
})
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { React } from 'react';

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>List</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testprojectnavigation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "firebase": "^10.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am using react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Answer (score 2):

In your

```js
{user ? <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false}} /> : <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false}} />}
```

If user is defined, go to Login, otherwise go to Home.
Don't you want this to be the other way around?

Comment: uff yes you're right... don't know how I could not see it, I checked the code for like a million times.... better go to sleep sometimes I guess. Thank you!